# How do I overlay a Highchart with a SVG graphic?

Tags: svg, highcharts

Is this possible?  I'd like to use my SVG graphic and not the individual Highcharts renderer drawing commands.

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you just want an SVG image on the chart?  http://jsfiddle.net/R8aQG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include an SVG image on a chart use the [renderer's image method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image%28%29).

```
chart.renderer.image('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg', 100, 100, 50, 50).add();
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R8aQG/).

Comment: Thanks, Mark!  I can get the smiley in my document.  How do I load a local .svg file in the same directory with my html page?

Comment: @turgo, A relative URL path should work, so `chart.renderer.image('some.svg')`

Comment: I still need help. I cannot get this svg code to render in my chart.  Ill add the svg code to my OP.

Comment: OK, I got it, the renderer.image command had too small a region exposed(50x50 from the example), and the svg image wasn't visible.  Thanks Mark!